# jquery code to go previous html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first I create array like this

```
var files = ['index2.html', 'index.html','index3.html','index4.html'];
```

then on back button click I want to go back one by one html page.but the thing is  i have pagecounter in it which link to the html page(describe in array) which I am loaded in div .and with click on back button I also want to update page number .for reference i am uploading the image.[image: Reference]
    function backbtn() {

```
        $("#txtPageNo").val() = i;
        //alert(y+'');
        alert('back files');
        var files = ['index2.html', 'index.html','index3.html','index4.html'];
        alert('array')

        while(i>=1 && i<=5)
        {
        alert(i+'')
        var file = files[i];

        $('#tabpage_1').load(file + '');

        document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = i-1; 
        i--;
        break;

        }
```

this is jquery code I write but It didn;t work like what I want.

Comment: Maybe you want `var i = $("#txtPageNo").val();` ?

Comment: yes i use this var a1 = $("#txtPageNo").val();
        alert(a1); and it works

Comment: guys i am not able to add any more question in stackover flow.plz help me to get through this

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
javascript.history.go(-1);
```

Or:

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: As I mentioned I also to maintain the page no history go is not working in my case

Comment: You also want to "maintain the page" so you don't want to load a new page?

Comment: I am loading html pages on click of next/back button one by one in my Div tag.at the top i am displaying page number also like 1 of 5 2 of 5it works with next function but my logic is not working with next button.and window.history is not going to help me in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.history.back()`

Or if you want it exactly for your case although history.back is better.

```
var current=window.history.pathname.replace("index", "").replace(".html", "");
window.location = "index" + --current + ".html";
```

As I said above using window.history is a better method though.

Hope it helps

Comment: window.history is such a basic method that I know but here in this case my scinario is different

Answer (score 0):

following is the code I use in for next and back button.

Next Button with updating page counter.

```
function nextbtn() {

        alert(txtPageNo.value+'');  
        //alert(i+'')
        alert('load files');

        var files = ['index2.html', 'index1.html','index3.html','index4.html'];
        while(txtPageNo.value<numItems )
            {
//              alert(i+'')
                alert(txtPageNo.value+'')
                var file = files[txtPageNo.value];

                $('#tabpage_1').load(file + '');
                document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = txtPageNo.value++  ; 
                txtPageNo.value++;
                break;

            }


        }
```

Back Button with updating pagecounter

```
function backbtn() {

        var a1 = $("#txtPageNo").val();
        alert(a1);
        alert('back files');
        var files = ['index2.html', 'index1.html','index3.html','index4.html'];
        alert('array')

        while(a1>=1 && a1<=numItems)
        {


        document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = a1-1; 
        a1 = a1 -2;
        alert(a1+'')
        var file = files[a1];

        $('#tabpage_1').load(file + '');
        break;

        }
        }
```